# Prepared Statement for a select percentage sql

Tags: java, sql-server-2008

I want to allow a user to select a randomized % of records. Like maybe 10% or 20% or anywhere inbetween. I tried using a prepared statement:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = cpds.getConnection();
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT TOP ?  PERCENT Table.Name, FROM Table"
            " WHERE Table.Color = ?"+
    stmt.setString(1, percentVal);
    stmt.setString(2, colorVal);
 } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try {con.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
    try {rs.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
    try {stmt.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
}
```

But I get a nullpointerexception.

What I know WILL work is

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

try {
    con = cpds.getConnection();
    stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT TOP "+percentVal+" PERCENT Table.Name, FROM Table"
            " WHERE Table.Color = ?"+
    stmt.setString(1, colorVal);
 } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    try {con.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
    try {rs.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
    try {stmt.close();} catch (SQLException e1) {}
}
```

But I think this is vulnerable to a sql injection? Is there a good practice for how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-compiled server-side prepared statements are designed for efficiency, less overhead, and preventing injection. 
But they may not be designed to handle a placeholder in the SELECT clause. For example, MySQL specifies some details about valid placeholder locations here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Check the specs for your specific DB and driver to confirm if it is valid.

Beyond that, you will be doing some validation of the user's input, to avoid SQL errors caused by out-of-range values (e.g. SELECT TOP 200 PERCENT) or non-numeric values (e.g. SELECT TOP ABC PERCENT). Given that, you could clean the percent data and prepare the statement from that point.

Comment: So there's no way around writing "SELECT TOP "+percentVal+" PERCENT..." right? If I validate the percentVal before sticking it in the statement, I should be fine?

Comment: No need to stick in the user's input directly. You could use Integer.parseInt as part of your validation and use it instead, which you can then guarantee is a numeric value and not an injection attempt. Or Double.parseDouble or Float.parseFloat if they are more appropriate for your input.